# Давно не(?)мытый и еще дольше не(?)чёсан(?)ый

Tags: орфография

Подскажите, пожалуйста: "Гундел маленький и не только давно не(?)мытый, но и еще дольше не(?)чесан(н)ый мужик". Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Если коротко: *не мытый, не чесанный;* объяснение для всех случаев примерно одинаковое: страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, имеющее при себе зависимое слово.

Answer (score 2):

"Гундел маленький и не только давно не мытый, но и ещё дольше не чёсанный мужик".

Если при полных формах причастий имеются зависимые слова (здесь — давно, ещё дольше), то отрицание *не* пишется раздельно.

Если страдательное причастиях прошедшего времени имеет при себе зависимые слова (здесь — ещё дольше), то в нём пишется *нн*.

Answer (score 0):

Первые два ответа - верные.

Answer (score 0):

Само предложение - безграмотный бред!

Answer (score -1):

: "Гундел маленький и не только давно немытый(синоним

"грязный"), но и еще дольше нечесанный(страдательное причастие с -нн-, и  пишется слитно с не т.к. нет слова чесанный) мужик"

Comment: Безграмотный бред. Подозреваю, что г-жа карина-со-строчной не догадывается о том, что причастие и прилагательное – разные части речи. Приношу извинения за прямоту.

Comment: про то, что такое прилагательное и причастие я знааю,не вам еня учить.
а то, что это прилагательное, не отрицаю.

Comment: Это **не** прилагательное. Это причастие. А правило вы приводите для прилагательного. Карина, я хотел было извиниться перед вами, ибо прочёл в другой ветке, что русский – не ваш родной язык. Но теперь, увы, желание отпало.

Comment: я русский всегда знала хорошо. просто правила вспоминаю,т.к. школу закончила давно и учусь на экономиста. хочу поступить на филолога